# Crystal Report Preview shows half of the page in vertical view

Tags: crystal-reports

[image]

My Crystal Report Shows only Half of the page in Preview and the other half side is inaccessible in design part.

The Greyed out part is not shown in preview.

And I couldnt change the greyed out part to normal one .

Comment: The question is off topic and should be close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is Because i set my default printer to thermal printer who's paper size is 3 inch. when i changed the default printer to my A4 HP Printer the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

for the printer setup

path : `-**Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Devices and Printers**`.

open my computer and paste it on above bar.

and you can choose the default one .that is "**Microsoft XPS Document Writer**"

.It is done .Now your crystal report will come fine.Enjoy

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please note that this answer already has an accepted answer. Unless your new answer provides added value it is redundant and will likely not give you any reputation. As a new user it pays off to work on questions without answers or ask good questions yourself.